# factory_boy extract original kwargs

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm building a factory with `factory_boy` that generates a django model. I would like to see what arguments the user inputs inline. My factory itself looks like this

```
class SomeFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'Instance #{}'.format(n))
    some_other_thing = factory.SubFactory(SomeOtherFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

Now the user could say `s = SomeFactory()` and it would work fine, but I want to detect if the user input their own argument. For instance, to tell if the user passed in their own name, as in `s = SomeFactory(name='Matt')`

What I've tried so far is

- Writing my own `__init__` function in the `SomeFactory` class

  - This gets mysteriously overwritten and is neither called when I call `s = SomeFactory()`, nor when I call `s.__init__()`
- Same goes for overwriting the `__new__` method
- Overwriting the poorly named `_adjust_kwargs`

  - This gives me all fields as `kwargs`, not just the ones the user defined. For instance, calling `s = SomeFactory(name='Matt')`, I would get a `kwargs` dict with keys for `name` and `some_other_thing`, which makes it impossible to tell input their own argument or not
- Overwriting `_create`

  - Still encounter the same problem with overwriting `_adjust_kwargs`, in that `kwargs` doesn't contain the original `kwargs`, but rather all of the arguments

I think a lot of the functionality I'm after is black-boxed inside of `factory_boy`'s `StepBuilder` (I suspect it's in the `instantiate` method) but I have no idea how to modify it to do what I want.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to figure out which `kwargs` were set originally in the call to `s = SomeFactory()`? I.e. determine that if I said `s = SomeFactory(name='Matt')`, that the user manually set the name?

Thanks!

Update: I'm running `django` version `1.11.2`, `factory_boy` version `2.8.1`, and `python` version `3.5.2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `create` method to only get the user kwargs.

A full example would be something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import factory


class UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    username = factory.Sequence(
        lambda n: 'test'
    )
    email = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user{0}@example.com'.format(n))

    class Meta:
        model = User

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):

        # here you'll only have the kwargs that were entered manually

        print(str(kwargs))

        return super(UserFactory, cls).create(**kwargs)
```

So when I call it:

```
In [2]: UserFactory(username='foobar')
{'username': 'foobar'}
Out[2]: <User: foobar>
```

If you want to catch kwargs for other build strategies than `create`, you would also need to do this for the `stub` and `build` method.